Is a concave parametric curve along a concave surface guaranteed to be concave along another concave surface?
Take a parametrized probability distribution $\mathbf{p}(\theta)=( p_0(\theta),p_1(\theta),\cdots p_n(\theta))$ and two permutation-symmetric, everywhere-concave functions $S_1(\mathbf{p})$ and $S_2(\mathbf{p})$ over that probability distribution. If a particular parametric curve $S_1(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$ is a concave function of $\theta$, can we conclude anything about the concavity of such a parametric curve for the other function, $S_2(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$?
Does it help if the parametric curves are always symmetric or even about some value of $\theta$, in the sense that $\mathbf{p}(\theta)=\mathrm{permutation}[\mathbf{p}(1-\theta)]$ for symmetry about $\theta=1/2$? Or, at least, can one infer that the two functions share the same maximum; i.e., that $\arg\max_\theta S_2(\mathbf{p}(\theta))= \arg\max_\theta S_1(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$ (which occurs at $\theta=1/2$ when the parametric curves are even about $\theta=1/2$)?
Some details:

I take $0<p_i<1$ and set $p_0=1-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$ without loss of generality; $S_1$ and $S_2$ are thus defined on $n$-dimensional simplexes. None of the maxima occur at the boundaries of the simplex.
All of the functional dependences can be as smooth as one likes to ensure differentiability. I can take each $p_i(\theta)$ to be some finite-degree polynomial in $\theta$.
The functions $S_i$ share a global maximum at $\mathbf{p}\propto(1,1,\cdots,1)$. So, if the parametrized curve happens to have that point in its domain, then the functions will share a maximum.
I am in particular interested in functions like entropies $S_1(\mathbf{p})=-\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\log( p_i)$, [minus] norms $S_2(\mathbf{p})=-\sum_{i=0}^n p_i^2$, and [log] symmetric polynomials $S_3(\mathbf{p})=\log(\prod_{i=0}^n p_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n\log(p_i)$. The slopes in any of the $n$ orthogonal directions all always have the same signs, being
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial p_i}&=-\log(p_i)+\log(p_0)=\log(p_0/p_i),\\
\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial p_i}&=2(p_0-p_i),\\
\frac{\partial S_3}{\partial p_i}&=\frac{1}{p_i}-\frac{1}{p_0}=\frac{p_0-p_i}{p_ip_0}.
\end{align} That means that, if the curve $\mathbf{p}(\theta)$ only goes along one direction that changes a single $p_i$ value, then all of the functions $S_i$ will be monotonic with each other. But a directional derivative in another direction may not always have the same sign for each function and in general it does not.
The second derivatives are all negative everywhere:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 S_1}{\partial p_i\partial p_j}&=-\frac{\delta_{ij}}{p_i}-\frac{1}{p_0}\leq 0,\\
\frac{\partial^2 S_2}{\partial p_i\partial p_j}&=-2(1+\delta_{ij})\leq 0,\\
\frac{\partial^2 S_3}{\partial p_i\partial p_j}&=-\frac{\delta_{ij}}{p_i^2}-\frac{1}{p_0^2}\leq 0,
\end{align} which is not enough to state that each of them is concave everywhere. That they are concave everywhere can be verified by making sure the negative of the matrices are positive definite, because all of their principal minors' determinants can be calculated using rank-one updates of positive diagonal matrices plus outer products of vectors-of-ones. That they are concave everywhere also follows by definition from: (1) Shannon entropy is concave in probabilities, (2) norms are convex so the minus sign makes this concave, and (3) $\log\det(X)$ is concave and we can set $\mathbf{p}$ to be the eigenvalues of a matrix $X$.
The functions $S_i$ are all Schur-concave due to being permutation symmetric and everywhere concave (one can verify the Schur-Ostrowski criterion for the above examples). This means that, if one probability $\mathbf{p}$ majorizes another $\mathbf{q}$, we will have $S_1(\mathbf{p})\leq S_1(\mathbf{q})$, $S_2(\mathbf{p})\leq S_2(\mathbf{q})$, $S_3(\mathbf{p})\leq S_3(\mathbf{q})$. Thus, if the parametric curve $\mathbf{p}(\theta)$ takes a path whereby there is a fixed majorization relation between each pair $\mathbf{p}(\theta)$ and $\mathbf{p}(\theta+d\theta)$ for small $d\theta$, and one can guarantee that the function $S_1(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$ is monotonically increasing with $\theta$ until some $\theta_{\rm{max}}=\arg\max_\theta S_1(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$ after which it is monotonically decreasing in $\theta$ (due to assumed concavity of $S_1(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$), then the other functions $S_2(\mathbf{p}(\theta))$ will be monotonically increasing with $\theta< \theta_{\rm{max}}$ and monotonically decreasing with $\theta > \theta_{\rm{max}}$.
The functions do not necessarily order all distributions in the same way. For example, one can find $S_1(\mathbf{p})< S_1(\mathbf{q})< S_1(\mathbf{r})$ and $S_2(\mathbf{p})< S_2(\mathbf{r})< S_2(\mathbf{q})$. This can only occur when the probabilities do not have fixed majorization relations, which they do not necessarily have when parametrized as $\mathbf{p}(\theta)$.

A generic curve along a concave function may do a wide variety of things, but constraining the curve itself to be concave and symmetric feels like it should constrain the probability distribution's path.
This problem came up in dealing with parametrized quantum states, for which it is challenging to analytically find the probability distributions $\mathbf{p}(\theta)$, but it is more straightforward to calculate global functions that correspond to these permutation-symmetric, everywhere concave functions. I can prove some optimization properties of these functions for $S_3$ versus $\theta$ and I want to prove optimization properties of $S_1$ or $S_2$ - the question here is whether I can get the latter for free because I've proven the former.

The answer seems to be negative. Taking the second derivatives, I find
$$\frac{\partial^2 S_k}{\partial \theta^2}=\sum_i \frac{\partial S_k}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial^2 p_i}{\partial \theta^2}+\sum_{ij} \frac{\partial^2 S_k}{\partial p_i\partial p_j}\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial \theta}.$$ The negativity of this expression for one $k$ does not imply its negativity for all $k$, as can be seen by a direct counter example.
Specifically,
$$\frac{\partial^2 S_3}{\partial \theta^2}=-\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{p_i^2}\left(\left(\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \theta}\right)^2-p_i\frac{\partial^2 p_i}{\partial \theta^2}\right)$$
and
$$\frac{\partial^2 S_2}{\partial \theta^2}=-2\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\left(\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \theta}\right)^2+p_i\frac{\partial^2 p_i}{\partial \theta^2}\right).$$
Take $p_{i>0}=-\theta^2+1/n$ and $p_0=n\theta^2$. This is normalized, and valid probability distribution for $\theta^2<1/n$. With tiny $\theta$, the curvature of $S_3$ is negative while that of $S_2$ is positive.
Starting with the easier one, $S_2$, we find
$$\frac{\partial^2 S_2}{\partial \theta^2}=-2\left(n(-2\theta)^2+(2n\theta)^2+n(-\theta^2+1/n)(-2)+n\theta^2 (2n)\right)=-4\left(3\theta^2(n^2+n)-1\right),$$ which is positive for small $\theta^2<1/(3n(n+1))$. But $S_3$'s curvature is always negative for sufficiently small $\theta$, where we find
$$\frac{\partial^2 S_3}{\partial \theta^2}=-\left(n\frac{(-2\theta)^2}{(-\theta^2+1/n)^2}+\frac{(2n\theta)^2}{(n\theta^2)^2}+n\frac{-2}{-\theta^2+1/n}+\frac{-2n}{n\theta^2}\right)=-2n/\theta^2 +\mathcal{O}(1)$$ (it's exactly $-\frac{2}{(-\theta^2+n)^2}\left(1+n\theta^2+(-\theta^2+n)^2/\theta^2\right)$, so it's actually everywhere negative here).
We thus have a counterexample where the negative curvature of $S_3$ does not imply the negative curvature of $S_2$ along the same parametrized path.
